# QGIS zonalstatisticsfb returns NULL

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, zonal-statistics

I am trying to calculate the population count (raster geotiff) lying under a polygon (vector layer). The appropriate QGIS library `zonalstatisticsfb` sum returns `NULL`. My QGIS python code is:

```
processing.run("qgis:zonalstatisticsfb", { 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : '_', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/Benedikt/test/isos.shp', 'INPUT_RASTER' : 'C:/Users/Benedikt/test/BY-AT.tif', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/Benedikt/test/out.shp', 'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 'STATISTICS' : [1] })
```

Input files can be obtained [here in googledrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/107R2h2cuvayRH0pPNBlbcTUOQ5tM7z-3?usp=sharing)

The `isos.shp` attributes already contain the population count from openrouteservice isochrone population count (which I want to imitate). Why does QGIS calculate `NULL`? BTW: The QGIS Plugin creates the same result --> `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS calculates **NULL** because both layers have not the same projection. Layer named **isos** has EPSG:4326 and **BY-AT** raster has EPSG:54009 (World_Mollweide-Projected). I got your same result by using these layers in this situation. However, when I clipped and projected raster to EPSG:4326, a NULL different result is obtained. For testing my approach, I used following script:

```
import processing

registry = QgsProject.instance()

isos = registry.mapLayersByName('isos')
BY_AT_4326 = registry.mapLayersByName('BY-AT_4326')

processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:zonalstatisticsfb", 
                             { 'COLUMN_PREFIX' : '_', 
                             'INPUT' : isos[0], 
                             'INPUT_RASTER' : BY_AT_4326[0], 
                             'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 
                             'RASTER_BAND' : 1, 
                             'STATISTICS' : [1] })
```

Layers look as follow after running script. Observe that the attributes table of layer with zonal statistic has **_sum** field (3,300,885). It was added for each pixel below this vector layer the value of 22,455 (true population count); much lower than obtained value of 3,300,885. So, for obtaining adequate values of population you can use mean or maximum instead (minimum returns zero because shapefile "touch" some pixels with this value). These statistics correspond to 'STATISTICS' : [2,6] used as processing parameter.

[image]

Comment: gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer did it! However, sum is the right way to calculate total population. I was able to compute numbers very close to ORS population count. Thanx a lot!